# In linode production Delayed jobs gets stopped after sometime

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, delayed-job, linode

I am using delayed_jobs 3.0 gem for email notification in my rails3 app. It is deployed on linode using nginx+capistrano. My linode config is RAM of 512MB and storage space of 24GB. In that two instances are running.

Delayed jobs of second instance is giving the problem. After sometime it gets shutdown and needs manually restart. There are no errors on Production.log and delayed_jobs.log. When I issue command "free -m", it shows the result as:
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           496        415         80          0          5         45
-/+ buffers/cache:        364        131
Swap:          255        130        125

I am not able to find out the reason of it getting down and please suggest me the possible solution.

Comment: After DJ dies the log files indicate nothing.

running: ./script/delayed_job status

gives: /config/environment.rb:11: warning: already initialized constant VERIFY_PEER
pid-file for killed process 2983 found (/home/deployer/../tmp/pids/delayed_job.pid), deleting.
delayed_job: no instances running. Can u suggest the solution and way to debug it.